# Bokeh server not working for bar charts, but working for plots

Tags: python, bokeh

I have bokeh server working locally and I am able to run the movies example with the command: bokeh serve --show movies:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/movies

I have created a simple script to display a bar chart. Although it works when I display it as a static html file, as shown below, it doesn't work using bokeh serve:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.charts import Bar, output_file, show

dict_name = {
    'values': {
        'label_name': 44, 
        'label_name': 28, 
        'label_name': 22,
        'label_name': 20, 
        'label_name': 15,
        'label_name': 7, 
        'label_name': 6,
        'label_name': 4, 
        'label_name': 4,
        'label_name': 2, 
    }
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_name)
df['label'] = df.index
p = Bar(df, values='values', label='label', legend=False, 
title='title', 
        xlabel = "", ylabel = "")

output_file("bar.html")

show(p)
```

When executing bokeh serve on the directory or on the file, it opens up a blank page. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if the server is just not working with bar charts. Either way, I would really appreciate a solution or work-around. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the chart to `curdoc`. As it is you are not adding anything to the document, so when `bokeh serve` runs your script it just returns an blank document and shows that:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.charts import Bar, output_file, show

dict_name = {
    'values': {
        'label_name': 44,
        'label_name': 28,
        'label_name': 22,
        'label_name': 20,
        'label_name': 15,
        'label_name': 7,
        'label_name': 6,
        'label_name': 4,
        'label_name': 4,
        'label_name': 2,
    }
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_name)
df['label'] = df.index
p = Bar(df, values='values', label='label', legend=False,
title='title',
        xlabel = "", ylabel = "")

# this was missing, every bokeh serve "script" example has this
curdoc().add_root(p)
```